# Django ORM count by date

Tags: django, django-orm

I have Reservation model that has two fields:

```
start_date = models.DateField()
end_date = models.DateField()
```

I need to present occupancy report based on total number of room-nights in the month, assuming each reservation takes one room during the day.

So either I need to:

1. annotate each reservation with number of days (but only in the queried month) or
2. for each date lookup number of reservations: `filter(start_date__lte=date, end_date__gte=date)`

I've done solution 2 in python:

```
month, year = 9, 2023
cal = calendar.Calendar().itemonhtdates(year, month)
cal = [date for date in cal if date.month = month]

res = Reservation.objects.filter(Q(start_date__range=cal) | Q(end_date__range=cal))
occupied_rooms = 0
for d in date:
     occupied_room += res.filter(start_date__lte=d, end_date__gt=d).count()
```

But python solution is too slow. Is it possible to achieve same result on database level?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do the trick

```py
month, year = 9, 2023
first_day = date(day=1, month=month, year=year)
last_day = date(day=1, month=(month+1) % 12, year=year + (month+1) // 12) - timedelta(days=1)


# Exclude Reservation that are not overlapping the desired month 
qs = Reservation.objects.exclude(start_date__gte=last_day)
qs = qs.exclude(end_date__lte=first_day)

# Compute the number of nights that occurred in the month
qs = qs.alias(first_day_in_the_month=Case(When(start_date__lt=first_day, then=Value(first_day)), default=F("start_date")))
qs = qs.alias(last_day_in_the_month=Case(When(end_date__gt=last_day, then=Value(last_day)), default=F("end_date")))
qs = qs.annotate(night_in_the_month=Exctrat("last_day_in_the_month", "day")-Exctrat("first_day_in_the_month", "day"))

res = qs.aggregate(Sum("night_in_the_month"))
```

It does not take into account the night from the last day of a month to the first day of the next. It is unclear toward which month it should be added

Answer (score 0):

You only need the total number of `days` of the respective `month-year`. For that you can use [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange).

Then, you can build date objects and make a more precise lookup from day one to the last  day of the respective month, `annotating` each reservation `Object` with the number of days. And, if it is the total you want, then we can `aggregate` this `annotation`.

```py
month, year = 4, 2023
days_of_month = monthrange(year, month)

start = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
end = datetime.date(year, month, days_of_month[1])

reservations = (
    Reservation.objects.filter(Q(start_date__gte=start) & Q(end_date__lte=end))
    .annotate(occupancy=F("end_date__day") - F("start_date__day"))
    .aggregate(total_occupancy=Sum("occupancy"))
)
```